# Different models of Distributed Architecture

Tags: architecture, distributed

I just want to know different models to implement/design a distributed architecture.

I know some of the technologies in this field like

1. RPC
2. Java RMI & Socket
3. .Net Remoting & Socket
4. XML-RPC
5. SOAP based web service
6. HTTP based web application
7. REST ful web service

But there are lot more technologies that I know, but what are different models to implement distributed architecture?

Answer (score 1):

At an architecture level there are 4 ways to integrate systems:

- Shared Database
- Message Queue
- Request Response Call
- Message Transfer

Within each one there are many technologies that are available

Comment: Out of interest, what is the difference between message queue and message transfer?

Answer (score 1):

We can categorize architectures into 6 different types from one of videos of *Neal Ford; Mark Richards*

1. ***Traditional layered architecture*** like Model View Controller (*Spring MVC* etc)
2. ***Event driven architecture using Messaging API***, where an event has been dispatched to Queue/Topics & subscribers/receivers consume the events so that different components are loosely coupled
3. ***Service oriented architecture,*** very lengthy to explain but you can find lot of info from google
4. ***Pipe line (or filter) architecture*** - A message will be flown from producer to consumer through transformer and transformer modifies the message depending on business need
5. ***Micro kernel architecture*** ( plug and play) - It will have one core system, common to multiple components & specific components (plug-in module) ,which can be plugged in on need basis
6. ***Space based architecture*** - The architecture is scalable by adding more resources to it (it is best suitable if you are using non relational database like NoSQL database)

Answer (score 0):

You really should start with **requirements**, they have major impact on architecture.

- Single machine / multiple / multiple and geo-reduntant ?
- Shared / private memory / mix ?
- Synchronous / asynchronous communication / both ?
- Fault tolerance ? Recovery ?
- Scalability ? Transactions ?
- Large data / computationally intensive ?

Please add further questions I'm sure I forgot something important.